# Divide my data into a grid and select one point inside each box

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to do some calculation with a large dataset and I want to lower the amount of points I am using without losing the larger geometry. The idea is to divide the whole dataset into a 10 x 10 grid and have only one of the points inside each box (preferably as close to the center of the box as possible) go into my other code.

Say I have a random population like this

```py
x_rand = np.random.uniform(low=-20, high=20, size=(1000))
y_rand = np.random.uniform(low=-20, high=20, size=(1000))
```

I would want the result to look something like this (made this very quickly on paint so its not very rigorous. Red points would be the points the code would select) 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1mwx.png)
Im not sure if I should use np.split or make a boolean map or a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no where near a proper answer: it is wasteful with with memory in the redundant checking every `range_find` call and it only runs along the x=y axis. However, it show the very basics of how one could write it from scratch.

Basically, pick a region, find all the xs and ys that fall in that region, collect them, then compute the means, and store in separate array.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.uniform(low=-20, high=20, size=(1000))
y = np.random.uniform(low=-20, high=20, size=(1000)) 

def range_find(low,high,xs,ys): 
    _xs = []; _ys = [];
    if len(xs) != len(ys):
        print("Inputs must be the same size")
        return None
    i = 0
    while (i < len(xs)): 
        j = 0
        while (j < len(ys)): 
            if (low < float(xs[i]) < high) and (low < float(ys[j]) < high):
                #print(" ~xs[%d],ys[%d] -> (%f,%f)"%(i,j,xs[i],ys[j]))  
                _xs.append(xs[i]); _ys.append(ys[j]);
            j += 1
        i += 1
    xmean = np.mean(np.asarray(_xs))
    ymean = np.mean(np.asarray(_ys))
    #print("x-Mean: %f"%(xmean))
    #print("y-Mean: %f"%(ymean))
    return xmean, ymean 

xms = []; yms = [];
vs = range_find(-20.1,-16.0,x,y); xms.append(vs[0]);yms.append(vs[1]);
vs = range_find(-15.999,-12.0,x,y); xms.append(vs[0]);yms.append(vs[1]);
vs = range_find(-11.999,-8.0,x,y); xms.append(vs[0]);yms.append(vs[1]);
vs = range_find(-7.999,-4.0,x,y); xms.append(vs[0]);yms.append(vs[1]);
vs = range_find(-3.999,0.0,x,y); xms.append(vs[0]);yms.append(vs[1]);
vs = range_find(0.0,3.999,x,y); xms.append(vs[0]);yms.append(vs[1]);
vs = range_find(4.0,7.999,x,y); xms.append(vs[0]);yms.append(vs[1]);
vs = range_find(8.0,11.999,x,y); xms.append(vs[0]);yms.append(vs[1]);
vs = range_find(12.0,15.999,x,y); xms.append(vs[0]);yms.append(vs[1]);
vs = range_find(16.0,20.1,x,y); xms.append(vs[0]);yms.append(vs[1]);

xms = np.asarray(xms)
yms = np.asarray(yms)

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(x,y)
ax.set_yticks([-20.0, -16.0, -12.0, -8.0, -4.0, 0, 4.0, 8.0, 12.0, 16.0, 20.0])
ax.set_xticks([-20.0, -16.0, -12.0, -8.0, -4.0, 0, 4.0, 8.0, 12.0, 16.0, 20.0])
ax.yaxis.grid(True)
ax.xaxis.grid(True)
plt.scatter(xms,yms, color = "red")
```

[Scatter-plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjSbG.png)

EDIT: Added the grid tick markers for a 10x10 case

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a bunch sbaby171! I was able to generalize your answer into a function

```
def range_find(lowx,highx,lowy,highy,xs,ys): 
    _xs = []; _ys = [];
    i = 0
    while (i < len(xs)): 
        j = 0
        while (j < len(ys)): 
            if (lowx < xs[i] < highx) and (lowy < ys[j] < highy): 
                _xs.append(xs[i]); _ys.append(ys[j]);
            j += 1
        i += 1
    xmean = np.mean(np.asarray(_xs))
    ymean = np.mean(np.asarray(_ys))
    return xmean, ymean 

def make_grid(x,y,n):
    xsort = np.sort(x)
    ysort = np.sort(y)
    splitx = np.split(xsort, n)
    splity = np.split(ysort, n)

    lowx = np.zeros(n)
    lowy = np.zeros(n)
    highx = np.zeros(n)
    highy = np.zeros(n)

    for k in range (0,n):
        lowx[k] = np.nanmin(splitx[k])
        lowy[k] = np.nanmin(splity[k])
        highx[k] = np.nanmax(splitx[k])
        highy[k] = np.nanmax(splity[k])
    return lowx, highx, lowy, highy

def get_GridPoints(x,y,n):
    lowx,highx,lowy,highy = make_grid(x,y,n)
    xms = []
    yms = []
    print(lowx)
    print(highx)
    print(lowy)
    print(highy)
    for w in range(0,n):
        for t in range(0,n):
            xn,yn = range_find(lowx[w],highx[w],lowy[t],highy[t], x, y) 
            xms.append(xn)
            yms.append(yn)

    return np.array(xms), np.array(yms)
```

In the end my code returned this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yAOz.png